# Creating automated snapshots of Azure Resources and their dependencies to deploy at a later date

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm currently busy with an internship. In this internship I need to create a program which automatically creates "snapshots" of the current state of Azure Resources (And sometimes their dependencies) which need to be deployed to another environment. e.g. Acceptance -> Production. These snapshots must then be deployed to the new environment at a later date which has been coordinated with the client.

A solution can consists out of >100 Azure resources, ranging from API Managers, to LogicApps, CosmosDB's, etc. When a customer accepts or says "ok" to a few resources (= a part of the total solution) a snapshot needs to be made of that resource, in the specific state when the client said OK. That means that I also have to create a snapshot of the dependencies of that specific resource (LogicApp can depend on a CosmosDB, Keyvault etc).

And I can't just take a reference to the resource in the Acceptance environment, I need to bring that dependency over to production as well, seeing as it might be possible that another developer will continue working on said dependency which might break things.

I am bit of at a loss as to which direction to take here. I don't have a lot of experience with ARM (Templates) and I have been making several prototypes for a month now.

I have first tried to generate my own ARM (and Bicep) files through gathering information from the Azure Rest API, but I soon discovered this is not  viable because I cannot extract all of the information from that API to create said ARM file.

I then looked into modifying the generated ARM files from Azure itself. Whilst this is an option, it contains a lot of information which I do not need or want to transfer over to another environment. It is also very hard to determine which parts of the generated ARM file must be deleted, updated, copied or left alone. And then I still need to recursively get the ARM templates of the dependencies and go through those in an automated way as well.

Is modifying existing ARM templates the best route to go here? Or does a similar product already exist which might help achieve my goal?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would not go with the approach to modify exported ARM templates but I would go with approach of Infrastructure as Code i.e., I would created ARM templates as granular as possible i.e., may be one template per resource at the least and store that infrastructure code in a source repository and if required version it to use it in different environments. The reason for recommending one template per resource is to take care of the dependencies in a complex environment. I know this might look like a bigger activity for the first-time implementation but once the templates are integrated into any continuous integration and continuous deployment (CI/CD) tool like Azure DevOps then all of it can be automated with the help of release pipelines for fast and reliable application and infrastructure updates. For more information in this regard, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/) Azure documents.